# Convert hostname to IPAddr

Tags: c++, windows, api

How do I convert from a hostname (e.g. 'myhost') to a type of `IPAddr` using Windows API.  `IPAddr` is an unsigned long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (**edited**):

```
hostent * record = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
if(record == NULL)
{
    printf("%s is unavailable\n", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
}
in_addr * address = (in_addr * )record->h_addr;
string ip_address = inet_ntoa(* address);
IPAddr dst_ip = ::inet_addr( ip_address.c_str() );
```

Comment: yep, that gets me a IP address string, but not IPAddr (unsigned long).  Can you update your answer to add the following line: `IPAddr dst_ip = ::inet_addr( ip_address.c_str() );`